# Enabling SSL over Local Network Ubuntu SErver

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, camera

I have a web application within my office's local network, and I can access the web app via the server's IP address on other devices inside the network.

My problem is that the web app uses a web camera to take photos. However, the browser is failing to give camera access because it needs SSL to allow the use of the webcam.

How do I setup an SSL in my local network so that all the devices that is accessing the web app can use the camera?